History of words for a thing - the opposite of etymology?
What is a term that describes which words were used to describe a thing in the world?

Answering the question "How did people refer to ...?"
Is this a sub-discipline of linguistics?
Is it part of etymology?
Is it subsumed in the study of synonyms?

The following is an example to highlight what I am looking for.
Etymology studies the genesis of specific words. For example, I can consult the wiktionary page https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alcohol#English to find out that the word "alcohol" derives from Arabic/Aramaic/Akkadian expressions for stibium, and that it has been attested in (Middle) English since the 15th century.
On the other hand, I am unsure how to look up how the same substance has been referred to in English and adjacent languages before the word "alcohol" was commonly used. Ideally, this would include usage statistics and potential shifts of connotation of the respective expressions over time.
Certainly, "spirit" is a contender, though it might always have described liquids that contain alcohol, so it is not clear how the two meanings were differentiated.
This historical thesaurus also does not seem to provide a precise answer: https://www.oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=HistoricalThesaurus&q=alcohol
Is there a "???" such that searching the web for "alcohol+???" would be likely to lead to sources answering those questions?

"Onomasiology" is the study of what names are used to refer to a given thing or concept, so I suppose what you're after would be called "diachronic onomasiology". I don't know if there's such a thing as a diachronic onomasiological dictionary though or other corpus to search through, though. Searching for "onomasiological dictionary" did yield this PDF complaining about the lack of a good one, which you may find interesting: https://euralex.org/elx_proceedings/Euralex2000/027_Gerardo%20SIERRA_The%20onomasiological%20dictionary_a%20gap%20in%20lexicography.pdf

Can you say what '… in the world…' adds to 'which words were used to describe a thing…'?
